# Adding Routes to a React/Firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just starting to add React Routes to a React/firebase app. I had this code to read the data,

```
const fb = firebase  
.initializeApp(config)
.database()
.ref();

fb.on('value', snapshot => {  
  const store = snapshot.val();
  ReactDOM.render(
       <App {...store} />
    ,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
});
```

This worked correctly, with real time updates to the App.
I then started to play with Router,

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App {...store}} />
  </Router>
   ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But the {...store} gives an error, unexpected token. Should I move the Firebase code lower down the tree into the App component or is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

uh the `component=`doesn't take that thing that you have there with `ReactDOM.render()`

As you have it right now: store will be undefined... so set:

`let store = {} // at the top`

Where is your actual  component/class defined?
also you shouldn't creator render based on when Firebase shows up you should render first then when firebase shows up you can update the state.

So there is a lot that will need to be fixed here before this can work.

Here is my index.js:

also notice that store is the result of the configureStore (I'm assuming you want to use Redux as you have a store)...

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Root from './root/containers/Root'
import './index.css'
import configureStore from './root/store'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

const store = configureStore()
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)


render(
  <Root store={store} history={history} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import reducer from '../reducers'
import { database, initializeApp } from 'firebase'
import { firebaseConfig } from '../constants'
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const rootRef = database().ref().child('/react')
export const dateRef = rootRef.child('/date')

export default function configureStore(preloadedState){
  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, createLogger())
  )
  return store
}
```

And my Root:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import routes from './routes'
import { Router, } from 'react-router'

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Simplest Version to get started:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { firebaseConfig } from '../constants' //this is a must otherwise you have multiple versions of firebase running around...
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const rootRef = database().ref().child('/root')

class App extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    this.state = {store: {}}

    rootRef.on('value', snapshot => {
       this.setState({store: snapshot.val()});
    }

}
render(){
let { store } = this.state
let childrenWithProps = React.Children
.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { store: store });
});


return <div>
{JSON.stringify(store)}
{childrenWithProps}
</div>
}

}
const Routes = (<Route component={App}><Route component={Comp1} path='/earg'/><Route component={Comp2} path='/earg'/></Route>)

render(Routes, document.getElementById('root'))
```

This is a lot of code and you'll need still more to get this going... I'd recommend a tutorial perhaps...

Comment: Yes just learning here. The code was cut and pasted wrongly. The first version worked OK, but I take your point about rendering order. My problem is more of where to reference the store.

Comment: Am I correct that you mean store from react-redux /redux's Provider store? or what do you mean by store you'd just like all of the data in some object called store without Redux?

Comment: Yes, I'm just doing a quick test with Firebase before I launch into learning redux. In this case 'store' refers to the firebase database. Data comes through in real time before adding the Routes.

Comment: Ok so you should be able to access the stuff in the store by says this.props.store but you'll find that firebase doesn't really organize stuff in a convenient manner to be used directly... If you're not using redux and just want something quick I'd do something like inside `componentDidMount(){
const fb = firebase  
.initializeApp(config)
.database()
.ref();

fb.on('value', snapshot => {  
this.setState({store: snapshot.val()})
});
}`

Comment: Sounds logical. That would be within the lower App component then, so couldn't be shared across routes...? I think it would be easier to leave the Routes to learn later then. Thanks.

Comment: You can always pass along what is in the store to the next element using it's props: like inside App (which I use for my outer Route component) like 
`<Route component={App}>
    <IndexRoute path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/details' component={Details} />
</Route>`
then pass along that to the props of home and details like:
`const Details = ({store}) =>
{
return <div>
{JSON.stringify(store)}
</div>
}`

Comment: Then in the App extends component instead of saying regular children you have to pass the props to all the children:

`var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { store: this.state.store });
    });
return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
`
If this looks a bit weird (which it should) use Redux.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, for a quick solution, I used an anonymous function to wrap the component,

```
   <Route path="/" component={() => (<App {...store} />)} />
```